# How To Market A Series Of Books

Tags: publishing, marketing

Recently, I have been browsing writing jobs in several renowned freelancer sites, and I often come upon cheap propositions for ghost-writing a series of books ...well if you like working for peanuts. I feel I can come up with a series of books, but what do they do afterwards? How can you market your own work?

Comment: Try getting an agent? Send your work off to a publisher, with the help of an agent.

Comment: This question is unclear to me; I'll put it on hold, and let's clean it up.
If I understand you correctly, you're considering going into ghostwriting? You ask "what do [the series of books] do afterwards," but I don't see how that applies if you're ghostwriting for somebody else? You ask "How can you market your own work"; how does that relate to the propositions you find on freelancer sites?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what kind of book you're talking about? Fiction, non-fiction, memoir, children's books, something else?

Answer (score 1):

Reach out to book bloggers and offer them a free copy of your work in exchange for an honest review. If you have a series of books, offer the first one for free on Amazon whenever they allow it. This is an easy way to capture sales for the later books. You can also arrange a blog tour in order to promote your work, but if you are completely unknown you may have to pay for it.

Get involved in the community of authors and readers online. The challenge of self-publishing is always to get your book in front of it's audience. If you have a relationship with other fans, it's easier to do this.